# Presenting a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this list of names and different languages

```
(setq l '((david spanish german)
          (amanda italian spanish english)
          (tom german french)))
```

I want to do the next with a function: for each language, I need every name relationed with every language.

For example, if I call the function with the list L:

```
(lenguages L)
```

I want to show this:

```
  ( (english (amanda))
    (spanish (david amanda))
    (italian (amanda))
    (german(david tom))
    (french(tom))
  )
```

I have an idea of how to do this, but it shows just one item.

```
(defun lenguages(names)
   (cond((null names) nil)
    ((list (cadar names) (list (caar names))))))
```

this last function only show `(spanish (david))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iteration-based task like this is best suited to Common Lisp's immensely powerful `loop` macro. You can read all the details about this macro in [the GigaMonkeys book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html), but we'll just go over the parts you need for this problem here. Let's start with the function definition.

```
(defun lenguages (names)
  ...)
```

Inside this, we want to iterate over the provided list. We also want to collect some keys, so a hash table would be useful to have. Hash tables (called maps or dicts in many other languages) associate keys to values in a time-efficient way.

```
(loop with hash = (make-hash-table)
      for entry in names
      for name = (car entry)
      do ...
      finally ...)
```

The `loop` macro is very powerful and has a language all its own. The `with` clause declares a local variable, in this case a hash table. The first `for` defines an iteration variable. The loop will run with `entry` bound to each entry of `names` and will stop when it runs out of entries. The third line is another local variable, but unlike `with`, a `for` variable is rebound every time, so at each iteration `name` will be the first element of `entry`. The `do` block contains arbitrary Lisp code that will be executed each iteration, and `finally` contains a block of Lisp code to execute at the end of the loop.

Inside the `do` block, we want to add the person's name to the hash table entry for each language they know, so we need another `loop` to loop over the known languages.

```
(loop for lang in (cdr entry)
      do (push name (gethash lang hash)))
```

This loop goes inside the `do` block of the outer one. For each language in the person's list of known languages, we want to prepend that person's name onto the hash value for that language. Normally, we would have to consider the case in which the hash key doesn't exist, but luckily for us Common Lisp defaults to `nil` if the hash key doesn't exist, and prepending an element to `nil` creates a one-element list, which is just what we want.

Now, when this loop is done, the hash table will contain all the languages and keys and lists of people who know them as values. This is the data that you want, but it's not in the format you want. In fact, if we put this in our `finally` block

```
(return hash)
```

We would get some semi-useful output* that tells us we're on the right track.

```
#S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL ((TOM GERMAN FRENCH) . (TOM TOM))
   ((AMANDA ITALIAN SPANISH ENGLISH) . (AMANDA AMANDA AMANDA))
   ((DAVID SPANISH GERMAN) . (DAVID DAVID)))
```

Instead, let's do one more loop to convert this hash table to the list that you want it to be. Here's what we want in the `finally` block now.

```
(return (loop for key being the hash-keys of hash using (hash-value value)
              collect (list key value)))
```

This uses the relatively obscure `being` syntax for the `loop` macro, which allows easy iteration over hash tables. You should read this as: for every key-value pair, collect a list containing the key followed by the value into a list, then return the accumulated list. This is yet another of the `loop` macros interesting features: it tries to provide primitives for common use cases such as accumulating values into a list. And it comes in handy in cases like this.

Here's the complete code block.

```
(defun lenguages (names)
  (loop with hash = (make-hash-table)
        for entry in names
        for name = (car entry)
        do (loop for lang in (cdr entry)
                 do (push name (gethash lang hash)))
        finally (return (loop for key being the hash-keys of hash using (hash-value value)
                              collect (list key value)))))
```

That link I provided earlier is to the GigaMonkeys book on Common Lisp, which is [available online for free](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). I strongly encourage reading through it, as it's an amazing reference for all things Common Lisp. Especially if you're just starting out, that book can really set you in the right direction.

---

<sub>* Your output format may vary on this. The implementation chooses how to output structs.</sub>

Comment: its a good answer. You might consider using push instead of setf viz (push name (gethash lang hash '()) its a little more concise.

Comment: Gah you're right. My head was automatically thinking "I wish I had 'appendf' here" and I forgot that `push` was a thing.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, works perfect!. My last doubt is if exist a way to show the result like the example I put. I tried with Format t but don`t work.

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is that `format` is its own can of worms, just like `loop`. In fact, the format directive gets its own chapter in that book I referenced: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html. An output format like that is going to require more than a passing understanding of format directives, so I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is fine: here is a version which does not use `loop` or intermediate hashtables, but instead builds the required association-list directly.  It's worth comparing the efficiency of this against the hash-table-based one: it does a lot more searching down lists, but in practice, for small amounts of data such things are often faster (hashtables have nontrivial overhead in many implementations) and it will always use less storage as it builds no structure it does not return.

Note that:

- this will return results in a different order in general (it has no dependency on hash ordering);
- this will ensure there is only one occurrence of each person for each language: `(languages '((david german german)))` is `((german (david)))` not `((german (david david)))` -- it pays some performance cost (which could be ameliorated for large data using more hashtables) for doing this.

So, here it is:

```
(defun languages (people)
  (let ((langs '()))                    ;the map we are building
    (dolist (pl people langs)
      (destructuring-bind (person . person-languages) pl
        (dolist (lang person-languages)
          (let ((entry (assoc lang langs)))
            (if (not (null entry))
                ;; there's an entry for lang: add the person to it
                (pushnew person (second entry))
              ;; there is no entry, create one with person in it
              (setf langs `((,lang (,person)) ,@langs)))))))))
```

---

(Note also that the `loop` based version could use `loop`'s destructuring, which might be a little clearer.)

Comment: Thank you for the help!, It's good to have different versions of the solution!